# I have a div that works as a modal, how can I prevent scrolling in the divs behind it?

Tags: css

I want to know what would be the best practice to solve this problem, I just want to be able to scroll the modal and prevent `scrolling` on the elements below it.
the idea is to scroll ONLY in the modal, not in the divs below it

```css
html,
    body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    h3 {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height:2000px;
    }
    h1{
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }

    .modalContainer {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
      transition: all 300ms ease-out;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .modalShow {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    .modalHide {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <div id="modal" class="modalContainer modalShow">
       <h1>Content modal!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>


      </div>
      <h3>hello</h3>
 </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript and with your button to show the modal window apply a class to apply `overflow: hidden` with CSS like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var button = document.querySelector('button[name="show_modal"]');

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
let modal = document.querySelector('#modal');

    modal.classList.toggle('modalShow');
  
    if (modal.classList.contains('modalShow')) {
        document.body.classList.add("hideScroll");
        modal.classList.add('showScroll');
    }else{
        document.body.classList.remove("hideScroll");  
        modal.classList.remove('showScroll');
}
  });
});
```

```css
html,body {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .hideScroll {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .showScroll {
      overflow: scroll;
    }
 
    
    h3 {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height:2000px;
    }
    h1{
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }

    .modalContainer {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
      transition: all 300ms ease-out;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .modalShow {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    .modalHide {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div>
      <button name="show_modal">
        Show Modal
      </button>
      <div id="modal" class="modalContainer">
       <h1>Content modal!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
       <h1>Content modal1!</h1>


      </div>
      <h3>hello</h3>

 </div>
 </body>
```

Also here you can see other ways to prevent scrolling in your modal:
https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/

Comment: thanks, I can have scroll on my modal...

Comment: Sure apply the same but to your modal container.

Comment: this not works for me, I updated my code with more details

Comment: Sorry, I was confusing, I changed my answer, you can check if this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```css
html,
    body.modal {
      background-color: gray;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      left: 100px;
      right: 100px;
      bottom: 100px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    h3 {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      height:200px;
      overflow: none;
    }
    h1{
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid red;
    }

    .modalContainer {
    
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
      transition: all 300ms ease-out;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .modalShow {
      transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    .modalHide {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="modal" class="modalContainer modalShow">
   <h1>Content modal!</h1>
   <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
   <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
   <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
   <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
   <h1>Content modal1!</h1>
  </div>
  <h3>hello</h3>
 </div>
```

Also, were you aware you had a 2000px for your h3 div?

I made it look like what a modal should look like when it's opened; you had some h1 divs that were spilling out of your modal, but the key is an `overflow-y: hidden;` to `body.modal {}`.

I answered this question with the assumption you were not looking to implement any JavaScript.